# Google Apps Script - installable OnEdit trigger is not set after copy from a template spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I added some menus and enable a custom installable onEdit trigger in onOpen() as the following. All menus are set as expected, but the custom installable onEdit trigger is not set. It seems like it does not execute those lines for deleting and creating triggers. What is happening here? Solutions?

```
function onOpen() {

  var ass = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  ass.addMenu("TriggerOn", [null, {name: "Disable OnEditTrigger", functionName: "disableOnEditTrigger"}]);
  ass.addMenu("AlertOn", [null, {name: "Alert Off", functionName: "alertOff"}]);
  ass.addMenu("EmailBodyHtml", [null, {name: "TextBody", functionName: "textbody"}]);
  ass.addMenu("Setup", [null, {name: "MasterTemplate", functionName: "setMasterTemplate"}]);

  //delete all previous triggers
  var allTriggers = ScriptApp.getScriptTriggers();
  // Loop over all triggers
  for(var i=0; i < allTriggers.length; i++)
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(allTriggers[i]);

  // Create onEdit trigger using the Spreadsheet
  var onEditTrigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger("myOnEdit")
      .forSpreadsheet(ass)
      .onEdit()
      .create();

  ScriptProperties.setProperty("alert", "1");
  ScriptProperties.setProperty("emailbody", "htmlbody");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To corroborate the other response, I'd suggest you read the [documentation on triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers) where it is explained that simple triggers (like onEdit and onOpen) have a limited set of possible actions since they run without the authorization of the user... Adding a trigger is (although I never tried it in such a trigger) beyond its possible action as it needs to be authorized.  If you want to be sure, run it manually and see if the script asks for authorization (or may be it has done it already so try with another user account).

You could create an installable onOpen trigger that will prompt the user to authorize the concerned services, in this case you can name it differently to avoid confusion (although the name is non important in this case)

Hoping it is clear enough.

Comment: yes. onOpen is a simple trigger. Moving "creating new trigger" code into menu item function works.

Answer (score 0):

From checking with a try-catch around your code (and dumping to Browser.MsgBox), it looks like you're bumping into security restrictions imposed by Apps Scripts. `"You do not have permission to call getScriptTriggers"` - similar problems exist with `newTrigger`, or basically anything with `ScriptApp`, it seems.  This isn't mentioned specifically in the restrictions [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers#Simple), but it seems likely this is the issue.  You may need to either hardcode this trigger in your script, or perhaps cause it to be created via another menu item.